# Origin of period function model of primes

Tags: geometry, number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, math-history

There is a web page attributed to Omar Pol, ["Sobre el patrón de los números primos: Determinación geométrica de los números primos y perfectos."](http://www.polprimos.com/) ("On the pattern of primes: Geometric Determination of prime and perfect numbers.") Figure 4 shows a geometric pattern that constructs the primes.  Also, Jason Davies built an interactive demonstration of this construction. (http://www.jasondavies.com/primos/)

Where and when was the geometric construction in [figure 4](http://www.polprimos.com/imagenes/numerosprimos01.jpg) originally published?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this

[image]

just a graphical representation of the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), published ["Introduction to Arithmetic"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Arithmetic) (60–120 AD) by Nicomachus...?

Comment: I looked through "Introduction to Arithmetic," but did not see a similar diagram. I am trying to determine who first came up with this specific diagram. (I did not see that Pol cited any sources - Pol may be the original author, but I do not know.) Although it may illustrate the Sieve of Eratosthenes, it is also a construction of the primes using only a straight edge and a compass, and has other interesting properties.

Answer (score 0):

Omar Pol is the original author of the diagram, put online circa 2007. It appears that other similar works were derived from Pol's original diagram.

A larger diagram (n = 1..16) is online at:
http://www.polprimos.com/imagenespub/poldiv01.jpg

(Source: Personal correspondence with Omar Pol.)